# No C wire for Nest thermostat but unused C terminal on furnace

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, nest

I know this question is similar to others I’m just hoping for a short answer. It’s a small house and the thermostat and furnace might be twenty feet apart. The control board on the furnace has an unused C terminal. The original thermostat only used three wires (W, G, R) with a copper jumper built into it between R and Rc terminals.

Can I run a wire by itself under the house from the C terminal on the furnace to the point in the wall where the three wire set comes out? Seems a little sketchy so maybe buy a small spool of four wire set and run that?[image]

Comment: Did you check that there are only three wires in the cable?  The other wire ends might have been snipped off.  The cable cover seems to look thicker than for just three wires.

Comment: Yes! I looked closer ad there is another wire in there. Now I’m hoping there’s enough slack on both ends to make it work. Google sent me one of those adapters but I think a true wire would be better.